# Magento 2.1.0 How to use SAVED CC as the only payment type? And allow customers to use a different delivery address?

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, delivery

```
Magento 2.1.0 
Enable Onepage Checkout = NO
```

I have 2 problems:

1. How to select a SAVED CC option as the only payment option? We do not want to use Paypal or any other real-time online processor. We process orders manually.
2. We deliver ALL products. How do we make the delivery address appear so that customers can fill that information in?

Answer (score 1):

1 ) It's against PCI standards to keep customer credit card info in your database. However, if you have valid reason, you can use the best available replacement: Payment methods which implement the Magento Vault interface. simply put, these save the credit card and customer info on their end and provide you with a reusable token (more on that [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-intro.html) ). I am fairly sure this feature is provided by braintree for magento2, and maybe some others as well (try googling "How is vault payment providers list gathered Magento 2" for more details on that). Authorize.Net CIM Payment Method also have this feature but as you process it manually it might not be a help to you

2) you can use this [tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) to add new fields to checkout but how is the delivery address is different from shipping address